# Innochecksum Error statting file: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: mysql

When i try to run command 
innochecksum -d {mysqldump_backup.sql} 
It returns 
--error statting file: Value too large for defined data type

I am able to load the  {mysqldump_backup.sql}.

Any pointers on why innochecksum is failing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have waited a long time for any probable answer to the above query.
The only probable answer in this case seems to be the fact that
32-bit version of innochecksum is not built with large file support by default. 
with reference to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55713
As mentioned in the bug above
Suggested fix:
Compile also 32-bit MySQL binaries with large file support because it can easily happen, that an InnoDB tablespace files gets bigger than 2 GB!
Which in my case is true as my input sql_dump to innochecksum is of 2.3 GB.

I think i got what i want however recompiling is a different matter hence closed.